# Width and height not applicable on span

Tags: html, css

My html span element doesnt respects width and height values specified by me. I know it's not a block element but if I dont want to make it block is there a way to make it work.

```
span{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the question?

Comment: A low quality question

Comment: the problem is that you are the only one who understand what you wrote ... your element doesn't respect, you don't want to make it block, you want to make it work ?

Comment: I request new users not to skip the guidelines. Please go through the guidelines carefully before asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for inline block. Set property to inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set your span to display inline-block:

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```